# Problem with migrating PHP5 functions to PHP7

Tags: php, mysqli

I have a core file in my project which contains all PHP functions I use. It's all written in PHP5.
Recently I've decided to learn and migrate to PHP7.

So this is my main file contents (simplified):

```
<?php

$db_host='localhost';
$db_user='root';
$db_pass='';
$db_name='migration';

$link = mysqli_connect($db_host, $db_user, $db_pass, $db_name);
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    echo mysqli_connect_error();
    exit();
}else{
    mysqli_query($link, "SET NAMES utf8");
    mysqli_query($link, "SET CHARACTER SET utf8" );
}

function dbquery($query) {
    $result = mysqli_query($link, $query);
    if (!$result) {
        echo mysqli_error($link);
        return false;
    } else {
        return $result;
    }
}

function dbarray($query) {
    $result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query);
    if (!$result) {
        echo mysqli_error($link);
        return false;
    } else {
        return $result;
    }
}

// Fetch the Site Settings from the database and store them in the $settings variable
$settings = dbarray(dbquery("SELECT * FROM site_settings"));

?>
```

Now the thing is, when I run the file, I get the following errors:

```
Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given
Warning: mysqli_error() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given
Warning: mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, bool given
Warning: mysqli_error() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given
```

Now, what am I doing wrong here?

**ADDITION**

When I started this file, I had `mysqli_connect` in a separate function.
So the connection was actually looked like this:

```
$link = dbconnect($db_host, $db_user, $db_pass, $db_name);

function dbconnect($db_host, $db_user, $db_pass, $db_name) {
    $db_connect = mysqli_connect($db_host, $db_user, $db_pass, $db_name);
    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
        echo mysqli_connect_error();
        exit();
    }
    mysqli_query($db_connect, "SET NAMES utf8");
    mysqli_query($db_connect, "SET CHARACTER SET utf8" );
}
```

But that `mysqli_connect` didn't seem to be working inside a function either.
Later on, I changed the codes to look like into what I wrote up there.

I really appreciate some help here.

**EDIT**

I've also tried making `$link` a global variable. But that didn't help.

Comment: Do you have to use mysqli? Why can't you switch over to PDO?

Comment: @Dharman I've always been using PHP5 structure, and I'm not a professional programmer. So when I decided to migrate to PHP7, I thought ```mysqli``` would be easier to implement and use. I have no idea how PDO works.

Comment: I recommend learning PDO. It has been available since PHP 5 and it is much easier to use and offers more functionality. Start learning it here https://phpdelusions.net/pdo

Comment: @Dharman Thanks a lot. I'll definitely have a look at PDO and try to learn it. But just for my own information, can you please tell me what was wrong with the code I tried with ```mysqli```? I read some basic guides and everything was written based on those guides. I just put them in my own functions.

Answer (score 2):

If you must use mysqli then it is a good idea to have wrapper functions. However, what you have at the moment is useless. Your functions are disjointed, you are not using parameterized prepared statements and you have not enabled mysqli exceptions.

The error you are getting is because you have not defined the variable in the scope you are in. Every time you require a variable inside a method/function you must pass it in as an argument to the function.

I would recommend creating a class instead. This class should have at least one helper function that will let you quickly execute a prepared statement.

```
class DBClass extends mysqli {
    public function __construct($host = null, $username = null, $passwd = null, $dbname = null, $port = null, $socket = null) {
        mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
        parent::__construct($host, $username, $passwd, $dbname, $port, $socket);
        $this->set_charset('utf8mb4');
    }

    /**
     * Executed prepared statement
     *
     * @param string $sql SQL query with placeholders e.g. SELECT * FROM users WHERE Id=?
     * @param array $params An array of parameters to be bound
     * @return array|null
     */
    public function safeQuery(string $sql, array $params = []): ?array {
        // prepare/bind/execute
        $stmt = $this->prepare($sql);
        if ($params) {
            $stmt->bind_param(str_repeat("s", count($params)), ...$params);
        }
        $stmt->execute();
        // If the query produces results then fetch them into multidimensional array
        if ($result = $stmt->get_result()) {
            return $result->fetch_all(MYSQLI_BOTH);
        }
        // return nothing if the query was successfully executed and it didn't produce results
        return null;
    }

    /**
     * Executed prepared statement but fetch a single row only
     *
     * @param string $sql SQL query with placeholders e.g. SELECT * FROM users WHERE Id=?
     * @param array $params An array of parameters to be bound
     * @return array|null
     */
    public function row(string $sql, array $params = []): ?array {
        // prepare/bind/execute
        $stmt = $this->prepare($sql);
        if ($params) {
            $stmt->bind_param(str_repeat("s", count($params)), ...$params);
        }
        $stmt->execute();
        // If the query produces results then fetch them into an array
        if ($result = $stmt->get_result()) {
            // here we use fetch_assoc to get a single associative array
            return $result->fetch_assoc();
        }
        // return nothing if the query was successfully executed and it didn't produce results
        return null;
    }
}
```

This is just a demonstration but you could follow the same design. However, I would recommend to use an existing solution instead of reinventing the wheel. I recommend [EasyDB](https://github.com/paragonie/easydb) which is a pretty good DB abstraction layer.